# Canvas - How to fill a square with two colors using createLinearGradient()?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm having problems making a square that has two colors in it. I found the functions createLinearGradient and addColorStop but it only fills the square with one color, which is blue.

How exactly do I fill this square properly? I'm having trouble understanding the parameters of the function it seems.

```
var c = canvas.getContext('2d'); // context object

var grad = c.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 100);

grad.addColorStop(0, "red");     //
grad.addColorStop(1, "blue");   //

// Fill a square:
c.fillStyle = grad;
c.fillRect(100, 100, 100, 100);
```

Answer (score 2):

fillStyles, like gradients and patterns are drawn relatively to the context's matrix, so your gradient is actually drawn above your rect:

```js
var c = canvas.getContext('2d'); // context object
var grad = c.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 100);

grad.addColorStop(0, "red");     //
grad.addColorStop(1, "blue");   //

c.fillStyle = grad;
// show the whole gradient
c.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
// OP's square
c.strokeRect(100, 100, 100, 100);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" height="300"></canvas>
```

To fix that you have two choices:

- Set your gradients params correctly from the beginning:

```js
var c = canvas.getContext('2d');
// move the y1 and y2 values by 100
var grad = c.createLinearGradient(0, 100, 0, 200);

grad.addColorStop(0, "red");     //
grad.addColorStop(1, "blue");   //

// Fill a square:
c.fillStyle = grad;
c.fillRect(100, 100, 100, 100);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" height="300"></canvas>
```

- Translate your context's matrix just before calling `fill()`. Indeed, path drawing and filling can be done on separate matrice.

```js
var c = canvas.getContext('2d');
var grad = c.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 100);

grad.addColorStop(0, "red");     //
grad.addColorStop(1, "blue");   //

c.fillStyle = grad;
// draw the path
c.rect(100, 100, 100, 100);
// change the filling matrix
c.translate(100, 100);
c.fill();

// reset the matrix
c.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" height="300"></canvas>
```

Comment: When you create the gradient, wouldn't you have to start the gradient at x=100 as well? Maybe Im not getting the math right but if x is at 0, wouldnt it just stay at the edge of the screen and only move vertically since only the y is changed?

Comment: It goes infinitely to the last color on every edges, so for a vertical gradient, that doesn't matter where the x line is it will spread the same way all along the x axis anyway. For an oblique one or horizontal one, then yes you would have to set it correctly.

Comment: Hmm, so when you create a linear gradient what are the coordinates being based off? Because I was trying to match the gradient with the square being on 100,100, but that didnt seem to work, is (0,0) on the gradient starting on the bottom left part of the square? Or is it starting on the coordinates of the whole canvas

Comment: The coordinates you give are the ones of a segment. And colors spreads infinitely from this segment in 4 directions. Just try to fill the whole canvas like the first snippet does, and try with different coordinates to accomodate yourself with the concept.

Answer (score 0):

Your values for `createLinearGradient`  were outside of the rectangle you were drawing in.

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('one');
const c = canvas.getContext('2d');
const grad = c.createLinearGradient(100, 100, 200, 200);
grad.addColorStop(0, "red");
grad.addColorStop(1, "blue");

c.fillStyle = grad;
c.fillRect(100, 100, 100, 100);
```

```css
canvas {
  outline: 1px solid black
}
```

```html
<canvas id="one" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
```

Comment: To be more specific, the coordinates in `createLinearGradient` and `fillRect` are independent from one another, so if the gradient doesn't happen within the coordinates defined by `fillRect`, it won't be visible at all.

Comment: Oh so the gradient has to match where the rectangle is, if i wanted to keep the rect at 100,100,100,100, where would the gradient have to be to cover it?

Comment: A rect at 100,100,100,100 is a rect with no size!! A rect at 0,0,100,100 is a rect with 100 width and 100 height.

Comment: @Intervalia no a rect 100,100,100,100 is a 100px square whose top left corner is at 100,100 coordinates. Params for rect are x,y,width,height

Comment: Ah, I forgot it was width and height and not bottom and right. Thanks for the reminder. Been too long since I wrote anything for Canvas.